# Who manned the turrets in the Falcon during the Battle of Endor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, millennium-falcon

In the final space battle in Return of the Jedi, we see that the Falcon is flown by Lando, with the Sullustian Nien Numb as co-pilot.  However, we never see the turrets fire, nor do we see any mention of them.  Since even the most minor of background characters will have a larger appearance in legends material, is it ever stated who manned the turrets in the Falcon during the Battle of Endor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but they cut the scenes they filmed for it. [Here are some outtakes.](https://youtu.be/vHnhxHMJcJ4?t=7m31s)

They seem to have been crewed by some male Rebels whom we don't see elsewhere in the films.